# How can I find the best values for the parameters that I will be using for Hyperparameter tuning of ML models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, hyperparameters

I am trying to omit out the trial and error method.

Comment: For any ML algorithm, you will have a definite number of hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

One common method for tuning hyperparameters of ML models is [Grid Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#Grid_search), where a predetermined subset of the hyperparameters are tested.

Another, more advanced and more efficient, option is [Bayesian Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_optimization), where sequential observations of model performance are used to to build a probabilistic mapping from the hyperparameters to the objective function.

Answer (score 0):

The general parameter value is not precisely defined. It requires research, try to define a parameter space and try to find the best fit for your model. Try using a [Hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) or common method for tuning hyperparameters.